# Make coutdown use localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am struggling to make this code to work with localStorage so if anyone can help me that would be amazing. How do I implement a localStorage in order to save the countdown when refreshing the page?

```
  var hour = 5 * 3600;
  var minute = 5 * 60;

  var deadline = hour + minute;

  function formatTime(seconds) {
    var hide = false;
    var h = Math.floor(seconds / 3600),
        m = Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60;
    return h + m;

  }


  var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

  function timer() {
    deadline--;
    if (deadline < 0) {
      return clearInterval(counter);
    } 

    $('#deadline').html(formatTime(deadline));
  }
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Making a countdown (seems you have that)?  Or storing a number in localStorage?  In which case, the countdown code appears to be irrelevant.

Comment: You do not seem to be using localStorage at all... I think you need more code to get an answer or describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: setInterval does not return a counter rather an id

Comment: I need to use localStorage so I can save the countdown when refreshing the page, I was trial and erroring but couldn't do it so have added countdown code so if anyone knows how to do it they can do with the code.

Comment: @EugenSunic for a variable name, colloquially it is a counter - it returns the id of the "counter", it's not "counting".  (I wouldn't call it that, but then I wouldn't call it `id` either).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in the localStorage everytime the value gets decreased. 
When you reload the page, check if the stored time exists, if yes store it in your deadline variable, otherwise let the deadline be the initial one.

```
 var hour = 5 * 3600;
 var minute = 5 * 60;

 var deadline = hour + minute;

 function formatTime(seconds) {
   var hide = false;
   var h = Math.floor(seconds / 3600),
     m = Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60;
   console.log(h)
   console.log(m)
   return h + m;

 }

 var counter;
 var storedTime = localStorage.getItem('deadline')
 if (storedTime) {
   deadline = Number(storedTime)
 }
 counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);



 function timer() {
   --deadline;
   localStorage.setItem('time', deadline);
   if (deadline < 0) {
     return clearInterval(counter);
   }

    $('#deadline').html(formatTime(deadline));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping man, unfortunately, it still resets when I refresh the page

Comment: hmm I don't how that's possible can you post a online demo?